# Shiny, create score from selectInputs

Tags: shiny

I'm very new to shiny and having some trouble creating a simple app. I am trying to use selectInputs to create a score. For example: if question 1=true and question 2=true then output value=2; if question 1=false and question 2=true then output value =1; and so on. I think the problem may be that I'm not grasping how reactivity works despite several reading the documentation (a lot). I also tried it with radio buttons and actions buttons with no luck.

Here's what I've got on the ui side:

```
ui.R
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("title"),
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput("var1", 
              label = "Some question 1",
              choices = c("True", "False"),
              selected = "True"),
      selectInput("var2", 
              label = "Some question 2",
              choices = c("True", "False"),
              selected = "True"),      
      submitButton(text = "Submit", icon = NULL, width = NULL)
    )
    )
   )
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of `submitButton` is generally discouraged in favor of the more versatile `actionButton` (which increases by 1 each time it is pressed).

In your `server.R` code you can create a reactive (`calc_score`) which takes a dependency on the `input$submit` (i.e. the `actionButton`) and then calculates the score (here checkboxes are used since TRUE and FALSE equals 1 and 0, respectively, so the sum of your checkbox values gives the score). Using isolate avoids a dependency on `input$var1` and `input$var2`, so `calc_score` does *not* trigger when the checkboxes change (only when `input$submit` changes, i.e. the `actionButton` is pressed).

Finally, `calc_score` only triggers if it is actually consumed by an output (in this case in the `output$score` function which renders text that is then included in the UI via `verbatimTextOutput("score")`)

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("title"),
    sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      checkboxInput("var1", label = "Some question 1", value = TRUE),
      checkboxInput("var2", label = "Some question 2", value = TRUE),      
      actionButton(inputId = "submit", label = "Submit", icon = NULL, width = NULL)
    ),
    mainPanel(
       verbatimTextOutput("score")
    ))))
server <- function(input, output) {

  calc_score <- reactive({
    input$submit
    isolate(sum(c(input$var1, input$var2)))
  })

   output$score <- renderText({
     calc_score()
   })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```